# How can I define colors and their range for a colorbar in matplotlib and offset data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot, offset, colorbar

Until now I used gnuplot to visualize my data and have very low experience in matplotlib and python. I have a file containing values (x,y,f1(x,y),f2(x,y),...). I want to do a 2D scatter plot, where the points (x,y) are colored by f(x,y).
How can I plot with a certain offset e.g. `f(x,y)-1` and how can I define the palette of the colorbar.

Currently my python script looks like this  (the following script uses a predefined color map `coolwarm`, but I need self-defined ones for different lines of my data):

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

x = np.loadtxt('disk_int_500p_a0000_theta45_r1D03.dat',
                 unpack=True)

plt.scatter(x[0], x[1], marker='+', s=150, linewidths=4, c=x[2], cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
plt.colorbar()    

plt.show()
```

The script I used in gnuplot looked like this, it shows what I mean by offset e.g. `($4 - 1.0)` and what I mean by defining a colorbar `set palette defined (z_min "blue", z_max/10 "green", z_max/3 "orange", z_max "red")`:

```
DATA = 'disk_int_500p_a0000_theta45_r1D03'

set size square
set xrange[-22:22] 
set yrange[-22:22]
set view map

set xlabel '$\alpha$ [M]'
set ylabel '$\beta$ [M]'

set object 1 rectangle from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 fillcolor rgb "black" behind

stats DATA.'.dat' using ($4 - 1.0) name "z" 

set palette defined (z_min "blue", z_max/10 "green", z_max/3 "orange", z_max "red")

splot DATA.'.dat' using ($1):($2):($4 - 1.0) with points pointtype 0 palette
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for, because it looks like you're already doing what you're asking for ('produce a nice colorbar').  What is wrong with the results of the script you already have?

Comment: @Ajean you are right the question was very unclear. I edited it. The basic question is how can I plot data with a certain offset and how can I define the color of a range of f(x,y).

Comment: Offsets are "list slicing" in Python -- you'll do something like `plot(x[1:], y[1:], c=f[0:-1])`, where x, f, c are columns of the overall table.